# Facebook iframe rails app without change now returns a "406 Not Acceptable" response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

Using facebooker gem. Two separate apps both start returning blank pages in the facebook app iframe and the rails logs show 406 errors.

Note that direct access to the site with the same url as called in the iframe works if the fb_sig parameter is dropped.

Have facebook changed either the parameters (naming) that they pass to an app or is it something to do with the deprecation of fbml? Or facebooker issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript FB.init call used to look something like:

```
FB.init("API_KEY", "xd_receiver.htm", ...
```

And now looks like (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.init/):

```
FB.init({
     appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
     status : true, // check login status
     cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
   });
```

I've also just had the useful "POST for Canvas" break things too, so thanks Michael.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem recently.

This could fix it:

Please check if Facebook turned on "POST for Canvas" in the "Advanced" tab in your application settings on www.facebook.com/developers/. If so, deactivate.

Hope this helps!